# Unable to deploy meteor on ubuntu using meteor-up

Tags: docker, ubuntu, meteor, mup

I'm unable to deploy meteor using `mup` and i'm getting the below errors

*Notes*

- My app name is `malfintech`
- Server: ubuntu (on premis)

Info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[10.1.140.30] - Start Meteor
[10.1.140.30] x Start Meteor: FAILED

              ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
              Error: No such image: mup-malfintech:latest
        Error: No such image: mup-malfintech:latest
        Error: No such image: mup-malfintech:previous
        Error: No such image: mup-malfintech:previous
        Error: No such image: mup-malfintech:latest
        Removing docker containers. Errors about nonexistent endpoints and containers are normal.
        Error: No such container: malfintech
        Error response from daemon: endpoint malfintech not found
        Error: No such container: malfintech-frontend
        Error response from daemon: endpoint malfintech-frontend not found
        Error: No such container: malfintech-nginx-letsencrypt
        Error response from daemon: endpoint malfintech-nginx-letsencrypt not found
        Error: No such container: malfintech-nginx-proxy
        Error response from daemon: endpoint malfintech-nginx-proxy not found
        Finished removing docker containers
        invalid reference format
        docker: open /opt/malfintech/config/env.list: no such file or directory.
        See 'docker run --help'.
```

Here is my `mup.js` config:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '***',
      username: 'dev',
      password: '*****'
    }
  },

  app: {
    name: 'malfintech',
    path: '../',
    type: 'meteor',
    docker: {
      image: './docker',
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
      buildLocation: '/tmp',
    },

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    env: {
      "WEB_URL": "https://malfintech.com",
      "ROOT_URL": "https://api.malfintech.com",
      "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://*****/***"
    },

    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },
};
```

`./docker` has a copy of [zodern/meteor](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-docker) image, only changing `USER` from `app` to `dev` (Wherever applies)

Happy to provide any info that would help solve the `vodo`

Comment: I don't think you can use a local docker image, can you? And if so, then how do you know how `.` will be resolved on the server you are deploying to?

Comment: i reverted back to the default `zodern/meteor`. Actually at first it was there, but then i suspected it would be permission issue. But it seems not

Comment: I assume you did a `mup setup` first, followed by a `mup deploy` ? 
And if you make changes to your `mup.json`, you need to do a `mup reconfig` to push them up?

Comment: it was not a `mup` problem. it was the docker source, i really can't remember how it was downloaded, but it wasn't `apt`. once removed and reinstalled using `apt` it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, If your server is local and already running docker, you might hit trouble. There are all sorts of dependencies with libraries on an existing server.

I have found that mup really prefers a 'raw' ubuntu install with nothing on it.

The reason being that it can set docker up exactly the way it likes it. You end up with a smoother experience too.

I would try using a new droplet or ec2 server to try it out.

Comment: actually it was a docker problem. It was installed on the server using some plugin manager (not apt), which caused all the troubles ever

Comment: it was not a `mup` problem